# How to strip all characters except numbers from text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a text column:

```
id   authorization
--------------------
 1   A1541-57
 2   135
 3   G-ff5
 4   BLA
 5   120G3
```

I want to write a query which shows the column but only with numbers, if there are no numbers show null

This is my desired output:

```
1 154157
2 135
3 5
4
5 1203
```

I know this could be done with regular expressions but I'm not sure how I do that in a query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex is the way to go:

```
select id, regexp_replace(authorization, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
from the_table;
```

`[^0-9]` means "anything that is not a digit

Comment: Or, to avoid using relatively slow regexp: `select id, translate(authorization, translate(authorization, '0123456789', ''), '') from the_table;`

Comment: Are you sure that's faster? Seems quite complex with the two `translate()` calls, especially for long strings.